# Getting a landscape table to work!

Tags: tables, landscape

My supervisor requested I make three vertical tables into one horizontal / landscape table. The code for my tables (at least the formatting part) were rather complex and this is my first attempt at a landscape table. Unfortunately, I am bit a stuck, and I think I know where I am going wrong (the column widths etc), but I am not sure how to fix it. I give a mock up of my table below to understand what I'd like to get at:

[image]

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siuntix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\begin{document}
\afterpage{
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}
\small
{ 
 >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{.17\textwidth} 
 S *{3}{S[table-format=2.1] >{\footnotesize}S[table-format=3.2,input-symbols=()]} }
  \caption {Descriptive Statistics (\%): Commerce, EBE and Science faculties}      
\label{table:DSCF} \\
\toprule
{\bfseries Variable} & 
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Commerce}\\
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries EBE} \\
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Science} \\
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Total} \\
\cmidrule{2-13}
&&
\multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Graduated} & \multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Academically Excluded} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Censored}
\multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Graduated} & \multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Academically Excluded} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Censored}
\multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Graduated} & \multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Academically Excluded} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Censored}
\multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Graduated} & \multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Academically Excluded} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Censored}\\
\midrule
\bfseries Total & 50.1 & 7.5 & 42.4 & 35.8 & 21.6 & 42.7 & 46.4 & 26.1 & 27.5 & & 45.8 & 14.9 & 39.3    \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Gender\\
Male                 & 49.6 & 8.7  & 41.7 & 36.4 & 21.9 & 41.7 & 44.0 & 31.2 & 24.9 & 44.3 & 17.3 & 38.5 \\
Female               & 50.7 & 6.2  & 43.1 & 33.8 & 20.6 & 45.7 & 49.3 & 20.2 & 30.5 & 48.0 & 11.5 & 40.5 \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Race\\
White & 59.8 & 3.0 & 37.2 & 50.8 & 7.8 & 41.3 & 64.5 & 5.1 & 30.4 & & 58.7 & 4.6 & 36.7  \\
Black & 38.7 & 13.1 & 48.2 & 22.2 &34.9& 43.0 & 31.0 & 44.5 & 24.5 & 32.5 & 26.3 &41.2(\\
Coloured & 49.8 & 7.4 & 42.8 & 36.4 & 21.9 & 41.6 & 40.2 & 30.6 & 29.2 & 44.5 & 16.1 & 39.5   \\
Indian/Asian & 48.9  & 7.9 & 43.3 & 32.7 & 20.5 & 46.9 & 32.7 & 20.5 & 46.9 & 44.6 & 13.3 & 42.1\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Financial Aid\\
Ineligible for Financial Aid & 52.1  & 5.5  & 42.4 & 38.0 & 17.7 & 44.3 & 38.0 & 17.7 & 44.3 & 48.7 & 10.6 & 40.7  \\
Eligible for Financial Aid  & 40.7 & 17.2 & 42.1 & 26.5 & 37.5 & 36.1 & 33.8 & 42.9 & 23.3 & 35.2 & 30.3 & 34.5 \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Programme\\
Mainstream  & 55.4  & 5.7 & 38.9 & 40.5 & 17.3 & 42.3 & 54.3 & 16.4 & 29.3 & 51.3 & 10.8 & 37.9  \\
Academic Development & 32.5 & 13.7 & 53.8 & 14.1 & 41.4 & 44.5 & 25.3 & 51.8 & 22.8 & 27.1 & 28.7 & 44.2 \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries English Home Language\\
Yes  & 55.1 & 4.9 & 39.9 & 44.1 & 13.3 & 42.6 & 56.3 & 14.1 & 29.6 & 52.8 & 8.6 & 38.6 \\
No & 38.8 & 13.4  & 47.8 & 22.3 &  35.0 & 42.7 & 32.7 & 42.7 & 24.6 & 32.8 & 26.6 & 40.6 \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries School Quintile\\
1  & 34.6 & 30.8 & 34.6 & 14.1 & 49.3 & 36.6 & 34.0 & 45.3 & 20.8 & 26.1 & 42.6 & 31.3  \\
2  & 30.2 & 16.0 & 53.8 & 25.6 & 36.4 & 38.0 & 28.8 & 50.9 & 20.3 & 28.1 & 35.1 & 36.8 \\
3  & 32.0 & 17.5 & 50.5 & 21.7 & 41.9 & 36.5 & 30.0 & 45.8 & 24.2 & 27.7 & 35.3 & 37.0 \\
4  & 37.7 & 17.7 & 44.5 & 17.7 & 38.0 & 44.3 & 30.0 & 46.7 & 23.3 & 29.5 & 32.0 & 38.5 \\
5  & 52.0 & 6.9 & (41.1 & 41.0 & 16.2 & 42.9 & 54.3 & 14.8 & 31.0 & 49.2 & 12.0 & 38.9  \\
Independent  & 52.5 & 5.3 & 42.2 & 40.7 & 13.9 & 45.5 & 54.3 &14.8 & 31.0  50.4 & 8.6 & 41.0 \\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Province}\\
Western Cape & 55.1 & 5.9 &39.0 & 42.1 &16.2 &41.7 & 52.0 &20.0 & 28.0 & 51.3 & 11.6 &37.0 \\
Non-Western Cape &46.8 & 8.6 & 44.6 & 31.6 & 25.1 & 43.3 & 41.5 & 31.5 & 27.1 & 41.9 & 17.2 &41.0\\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Year of First Registration} \\
{2006}  87.8 & 11.3 & 0.9 & 70.3 & 29.0 & 0.7 & 69.5 & 28.2 & 2.3 & 79.9 & 18.9 &1.2  \\
{2007} 88.2 & 10.1 &  1.7 & 68.7 & 30.0 & 1.4 & 68.5 & 30.8 & 0.7 & 79.4 &19.2 &1.4\\
{2008} 87.1 & 10.3 &  2.6 & 63.6 & 30.6 & 5.8 & 66.2 & 32.3 & 1.6 & 76.7 & 20.3 & 3.0 \\
{2009} 80.9 & 9.7 & 9.4 & 51.2   & 32.3 &16.5 & 51.9 & 43.9 & 4.2 & 64.9 & 24.9 & 10.2 \\
{2010} 62.6 & 6.4 & 31.1 & 36.8 & 19.0 & 44.2 & 69.8 & 21.0 & 9.3 & 57.5 & 12.7 & 29.8 \\
{2011} 15.8 & 7.2 & 77.0 & 0.0 & 18.2  & 81.8 & 37.3 & 23.4 & 39.8 & 15.3 & 12.8 & 71.9 \\
{2012} 0.0 & 5.4 & 94.6 &  0.0 & 7.5 & 92.5 & 0.0 & 13.4 & 86.6 & 0.0 & 7.5 & 92.5 \\
{2013} 0.0 & 1.7 & 98.3 & 0.0 & 4.9  & 95.1 & 0.0 & 5.1  & 94.9 & 0.0 & 3.0 & 97.0 \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
 }
\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to have confused the `table` enviroment with `tabular`, and there are several packages missing from the MWE (`array`, `ragged2e`, `siunitx`, `booktabs`).

Comment: And there's a custom column specification (`C`) missing. You seem to have taken the "minimal" concept a bit too far.

Comment: Thanks. Will update MWE as far as possible. Also the other complication is all the vertical tables were longtables, so also needed to delete other bits of code. I'm hoping it can fit on one page - I know 13 columns is a lot.

Comment: Environment `tabular` require specification of table width, i.e. instead \begin{tabular*} content of table ... \end{tabular*} it should be `\begin{tabular*}{\hsize} ... content of table ... \end{tabular*}`. Length `\hsize` you can replace with length of your choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would  recommend replacing the rather long column headings (Graduated, Academically Excluded, Censored) with abbreviations (G, AE, C), and describing the key in the caption. Then you can easily fit all the columns in a landscape page.

There are a lot of other small changes here and there. Not sure I remember all, but:

- New column specification. One `p` column followed by 12 `S` columns.
- Removed some parenthesis from a couple of the numbers.
- Removed some extra `&`, and also added some where required.
- `longtable` is used. The table is too long to fit in a single page I think.
- You had line breaks after each of the topmost column headings (Commerce, EBE etc.), those should be `&`.
- Four separate `cmidrule`s with some trimming, instead of one long.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape,ragged2e,array,siunitx,longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\small
\begin{longtable}{
 >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{.35\textwidth} 
 *{12}{S[table-format=2.1]}}
  \caption{Descriptive Statistics (\%): Commerce, EBE and Science faculties. Key: \textbf{G}: Graduate, \textbf{AE}: Academically Excluded, \textbf{C}: Censored}      
\label{table:DSCF} \\
\toprule
{\bfseries Variable} & 
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Commerce} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries EBE} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Science} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Total} \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-4}
\cmidrule(rl){5-7}
\cmidrule(rl){8-10}
\cmidrule(rl){11-13}
&
{\bfseries G} & {\bfseries AE} & 
{\bfseries C} &
{\bfseries G} & {\bfseries AE} & 
{\bfseries C} &
{\bfseries G} & {\bfseries AE} & 
{\bfseries C} &
{\bfseries G} & {\bfseries AE} & 
 {\bfseries C}\\
\midrule
\bfseries Total & 50.1 & 7.5 & 42.4 & 35.8 & 21.6 & 42.7 & 46.4 & 26.1 & 27.5 & 45.8 & 14.9 & 39.3    \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Gender\\
Male                 & 49.6 & 8.7  & 41.7 & 36.4 & 21.9 & 41.7 & 44.0 & 31.2 & 24.9 & 44.3 & 17.3 & 38.5 \\
Female               & 50.7 & 6.2  & 43.1 & 33.8 & 20.6 & 45.7 & 49.3 & 20.2 & 30.5 & 48.0 & 11.5 & 40.5 \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Race\\
White & 59.8 & 3.0 & 37.2 & 50.8 & 7.8 & 41.3 & 64.5 & 5.1 & 30.4 &  58.7 & 4.6 & 36.7  \\
Black & 38.7 & 13.1 & 48.2 & 22.2 &34.9& 43.0 & 31.0 & 44.5 & 24.5 & 32.5 & 26.3 &41.2\\
Coloured & 49.8 & 7.4 & 42.8 & 36.4 & 21.9 & 41.6 & 40.2 & 30.6 & 29.2 & 44.5 & 16.1 & 39.5   \\
Indian/Asian & 48.9  & 7.9 & 43.3 & 32.7 & 20.5 & 46.9 & 32.7 & 20.5 & 46.9 & 44.6 & 13.3 & 42.1\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Financial Aid\\
Ineligible for Financial Aid & 52.1  & 5.5  & 42.4 & 38.0 & 17.7 & 44.3 & 38.0 & 17.7 & 44.3 & 48.7 & 10.6 & 40.7  \\
Eligible for Financial Aid  & 40.7 & 17.2 & 42.1 & 26.5 & 37.5 & 36.1 & 33.8 & 42.9 & 23.3 & 35.2 & 30.3 & 34.5 \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Programme\\
Mainstream  & 55.4  & 5.7 & 38.9 & 40.5 & 17.3 & 42.3 & 54.3 & 16.4 & 29.3 & 51.3 & 10.8 & 37.9  \\
Academic Development & 32.5 & 13.7 & 53.8 & 14.1 & 41.4 & 44.5 & 25.3 & 51.8 & 22.8 & 27.1 & 28.7 & 44.2 \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries English Home Language\\
Yes  & 55.1 & 4.9 & 39.9 & 44.1 & 13.3 & 42.6 & 56.3 & 14.1 & 29.6 & 52.8 & 8.6 & 38.6 \\
No & 38.8 & 13.4  & 47.8 & 22.3 &  35.0 & 42.7 & 32.7 & 42.7 & 24.6 & 32.8 & 26.6 & 40.6 \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries School Quintile\\
1  & 34.6 & 30.8 & 34.6 & 14.1 & 49.3 & 36.6 & 34.0 & 45.3 & 20.8 & 26.1 & 42.6 & 31.3  \\
2  & 30.2 & 16.0 & 53.8 & 25.6 & 36.4 & 38.0 & 28.8 & 50.9 & 20.3 & 28.1 & 35.1 & 36.8 \\
3  & 32.0 & 17.5 & 50.5 & 21.7 & 41.9 & 36.5 & 30.0 & 45.8 & 24.2 & 27.7 & 35.3 & 37.0 \\
4  & 37.7 & 17.7 & 44.5 & 17.7 & 38.0 & 44.3 & 30.0 & 46.7 & 23.3 & 29.5 & 32.0 & 38.5 \\
5  & 52.0 & 6.9 & 41.1 & 41.0 & 16.2 & 42.9 & 54.3 & 14.8 & 31.0 & 49.2 & 12.0 & 38.9  \\
Independent  & 52.5 & 5.3 & 42.2 & 40.7 & 13.9 & 45.5 & 54.3 &14.8 & 31.0 & 50.4 & 8.6 & 41.0 \\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Province}\\
Western Cape & 55.1 & 5.9 &39.0 & 42.1 &16.2 &41.7 & 52.0 &20.0 & 28.0 & 51.3 & 11.6 &37.0 \\
Non-Western Cape &46.8 & 8.6 & 44.6 & 31.6 & 25.1 & 43.3 & 41.5 & 31.5 & 27.1 & 41.9 & 17.2 &41.0\\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Year of First Registration} \\
{2006} &  87.8 & 11.3 & 0.9 & 70.3 & 29.0 & 0.7 & 69.5 & 28.2 & 2.3 & 79.9 & 18.9 &1.2  \\
{2007} & 88.2 & 10.1 &  1.7 & 68.7 & 30.0 & 1.4 & 68.5 & 30.8 & 0.7 & 79.4 &19.2 &1.4\\
{2008} & 87.1 & 10.3 &  2.6 & 63.6 & 30.6 & 5.8 & 66.2 & 32.3 & 1.6 & 76.7 & 20.3 & 3.0 \\
{2009} & 80.9 & 9.7 & 9.4 & 51.2   & 32.3 &16.5 & 51.9 & 43.9 & 4.2 & 64.9 & 24.9 & 10.2 \\
{2010} & 62.6 & 6.4 & 31.1 & 36.8 & 19.0 & 44.2 & 69.8 & 21.0 & 9.3 & 57.5 & 12.7 & 29.8 \\
{2011} & 15.8 & 7.2 & 77.0 & 0.0 & 18.2  & 81.8 & 37.3 & 23.4 & 39.8 & 15.3 & 12.8 & 71.9 \\
{2012} & 0.0 & 5.4 & 94.6 &  0.0 & 7.5 & 92.5 & 0.0 & 13.4 & 86.6 & 0.0 & 7.5 & 92.5 \\
{2013} & 0.0 & 1.7 & 98.3 & 0.0 & 4.9  & 95.1 & 0.0 & 5.1  & 94.9 & 0.0 & 3.0 & 97.0 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Second option

By rewriting/shortening the entries in the first column and reducing the `\tabcolsep` you can actually squeeze the whole thing into one page in portrait mode. If the textblock in your actual document is wider than the default in `article` you will have more to go on, so you can make things wider than in the below code. (The frame in the screenshot comes from loading the `showframe` package, it's just there to demonstrate that the table is actually within the width of the textblock.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,siunitx,longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.7pt}
 \caption{Descriptive Statistics (\%): Commerce, EBE and Science faculties. Key: \textbf{G}: Graduate, \textbf{AE}: Academically Excluded, \textbf{C}: Censored}      
\label{table:DSCF}
\begin{tabular}{
 >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{.15\textwidth} 
 *{12}{S[table-format=2.1]}}
\toprule
{\bfseries Variable} & 
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Commerce} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries EBE} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Science} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Total} \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-4}
\cmidrule(rl){5-7}
\cmidrule(rl){8-10}
\cmidrule(rl){11-13}
&
{\bfseries G} & {\bfseries AE} & 
{\bfseries C} &
{\bfseries G} & {\bfseries AE} & 
{\bfseries C} &
{\bfseries G} & {\bfseries AE} & 
{\bfseries C} &
{\bfseries G} & {\bfseries AE} & 
 {\bfseries C}\\
\midrule
\bfseries Total & 50.1 & 7.5 & 42.4 & 35.8 & 21.6 & 42.7 & 46.4 & 26.1 & 27.5 & 45.8 & 14.9 & 39.3    \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Gender\\
Male                 & 49.6 & 8.7  & 41.7 & 36.4 & 21.9 & 41.7 & 44.0 & 31.2 & 24.9 & 44.3 & 17.3 & 38.5 \\
Female               & 50.7 & 6.2  & 43.1 & 33.8 & 20.6 & 45.7 & 49.3 & 20.2 & 30.5 & 48.0 & 11.5 & 40.5 \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Race\\
White & 59.8 & 3.0 & 37.2 & 50.8 & 7.8 & 41.3 & 64.5 & 5.1 & 30.4 &  58.7 & 4.6 & 36.7  \\
Black & 38.7 & 13.1 & 48.2 & 22.2 &34.9& 43.0 & 31.0 & 44.5 & 24.5 & 32.5 & 26.3 &41.2\\
Coloured & 49.8 & 7.4 & 42.8 & 36.4 & 21.9 & 41.6 & 40.2 & 30.6 & 29.2 & 44.5 & 16.1 & 39.5   \\
Indian/Asian & 48.9  & 7.9 & 43.3 & 32.7 & 20.5 & 46.9 & 32.7 & 20.5 & 46.9 & 44.6 & 13.3 & 42.1\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries Financial Aid}\\
Ineligible& 52.1  & 5.5  & 42.4 & 38.0 & 17.7 & 44.3 & 38.0 & 17.7 & 44.3 & 48.7 & 10.6 & 40.7  \\
Eligible & 40.7 & 17.2 & 42.1 & 26.5 & 37.5 & 36.1 & 33.8 & 42.9 & 23.3 & 35.2 & 30.3 & 34.5 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries Programme}\\
Mainstream  & 55.4  & 5.7 & 38.9 & 40.5 & 17.3 & 42.3 & 54.3 & 16.4 & 29.3 & 51.3 & 10.8 & 37.9  \\
Academic Dev. & 32.5 & 13.7 & 53.8 & 14.1 & 41.4 & 44.5 & 25.3 & 51.8 & 22.8 & 27.1 & 28.7 & 44.2 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries English Home Language}\\
Yes  & 55.1 & 4.9 & 39.9 & 44.1 & 13.3 & 42.6 & 56.3 & 14.1 & 29.6 & 52.8 & 8.6 & 38.6 \\
No & 38.8 & 13.4  & 47.8 & 22.3 &  35.0 & 42.7 & 32.7 & 42.7 & 24.6 & 32.8 & 26.6 & 40.6 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries School Quintile}\\
1  & 34.6 & 30.8 & 34.6 & 14.1 & 49.3 & 36.6 & 34.0 & 45.3 & 20.8 & 26.1 & 42.6 & 31.3  \\
2  & 30.2 & 16.0 & 53.8 & 25.6 & 36.4 & 38.0 & 28.8 & 50.9 & 20.3 & 28.1 & 35.1 & 36.8 \\
3  & 32.0 & 17.5 & 50.5 & 21.7 & 41.9 & 36.5 & 30.0 & 45.8 & 24.2 & 27.7 & 35.3 & 37.0 \\
4  & 37.7 & 17.7 & 44.5 & 17.7 & 38.0 & 44.3 & 30.0 & 46.7 & 23.3 & 29.5 & 32.0 & 38.5 \\
5  & 52.0 & 6.9 & 41.1 & 41.0 & 16.2 & 42.9 & 54.3 & 14.8 & 31.0 & 49.2 & 12.0 & 38.9  \\
Independent  & 52.5 & 5.3 & 42.2 & 40.7 & 13.9 & 45.5 & 54.3 &14.8 & 31.0 & 50.4 & 8.6 & 41.0 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries Western cape province}\\
Yes & 55.1 & 5.9 &39.0 & 42.1 &16.2 &41.7 & 52.0 &20.0 & 28.0 & 51.3 & 11.6 &37.0 \\
No &46.8 & 8.6 & 44.6 & 31.6 & 25.1 & 43.3 & 41.5 & 31.5 & 27.1 & 41.9 & 17.2 &41.0\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries Year of First Registration} \\
{2006} &  87.8 & 11.3 & 0.9 & 70.3 & 29.0 & 0.7 & 69.5 & 28.2 & 2.3 & 79.9 & 18.9 &1.2  \\
{2007} & 88.2 & 10.1 &  1.7 & 68.7 & 30.0 & 1.4 & 68.5 & 30.8 & 0.7 & 79.4 &19.2 &1.4\\
{2008} & 87.1 & 10.3 &  2.6 & 63.6 & 30.6 & 5.8 & 66.2 & 32.3 & 1.6 & 76.7 & 20.3 & 3.0 \\
{2009} & 80.9 & 9.7 & 9.4 & 51.2   & 32.3 &16.5 & 51.9 & 43.9 & 4.2 & 64.9 & 24.9 & 10.2 \\
{2010} & 62.6 & 6.4 & 31.1 & 36.8 & 19.0 & 44.2 & 69.8 & 21.0 & 9.3 & 57.5 & 12.7 & 29.8 \\
{2011} & 15.8 & 7.2 & 77.0 & 0.0 & 18.2  & 81.8 & 37.3 & 23.4 & 39.8 & 15.3 & 12.8 & 71.9 \\
{2012} & 0.0 & 5.4 & 94.6 &  0.0 & 7.5 & 92.5 & 0.0 & 13.4 & 86.6 & 0.0 & 7.5 & 92.5 \\
{2013} & 0.0 & 1.7 & 98.3 & 0.0 & 4.9  & 95.1 & 0.0 & 5.1  & 94.9 & 0.0 & 3.0 & 97.0 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks. Nice idea with the portrait as well. I actually might put that instead of the landscape table.

Comment: Hi @Tobjorn T - when I leave the out the '[H]' (as in \table [H]') so I can paste it there, this table does not fit on one page, but when I leave out the [H], it works perfectly. Also, when I leave out the [H], the table goes in the wrong place (about 2 pages down)...any ideas why this could be? Thanks

Comment: @Chris `table` is a floating environment, meaning that LaTeX can move it around a bit to avoid bad page breaks. Using `H` you disable floating, so it will be placed exactly where it is in the code. The size of the table is the same whether you use `H` or not, so that shouldn't affect whether it fits in one page or not.

Comment: I thought so too, but here's what I get without the [H] - works as intended: http://s4.postimg.org/fcnj5r055/Table_1.png ...then when I put in the [H], I get this: http://s4.postimg.org/r0hl0apa1/Table_2.png

Comment: @Chris Impossible to say exactly without a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). There's clearly something influencing the line spacing in the second case, but I at least cannot guess. Try building an MWE (described in the link above), and if that does not make the problem and/or solution evident, post a new question including said MWE.