# Fitting a huge table in one page

Tags: tables

I'm trying to fit the below table in one page either in landscape or portrait but unfortunately i'm not able to do it. please anyone can help getting it on page ??

```
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{crrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
    \toprule
    Tool Name  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Dymola} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Matlab/Simulink} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ETAP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{PSS/E} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Homer Pro} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Moasik} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ATP Designer} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{NEPLAN} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Transmission 2000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CYME} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DIgSILENT 
(PowerFactory)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SynerGEE 
Electric} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CAPE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Eurostag} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{IPSA 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MILSOFT 
Windmil} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SimPowerSystems} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MicroTran} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DSATools} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SIMPOW} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SKM 
Power*Tools} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Simulation Capabilities} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Dynamic Simulation & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} \\
    Power Flow Calculations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} \\
    Renewable Energies modeling (PV \& Wind) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{P} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} \\
    \textbf{Other capabilities } &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    is Programing required ? & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} \\
    Ability to export/import to other software & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} \\
    Verified Library & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} \\
    Availability in HS & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\checkmark} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-----} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please, see our [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to learn about our style.

Comment: Probably, you should swap rows and columns. Are your column heads really one-word?

Comment: `-----` the first three ligature to an em-dash and the second two ligature to an en-dash leaving two adjacent dashes of different lengths. Is that really what you want here?

Comment: Why all the `multicolumn`s? Is replacing the column headers with abbreviations an option? (similar to [Getting a landscape table to work!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268385), though I realize that situation is a bit different)

Comment: (Never mind that last suggestion of mine, don't think it's sufficient.)

Comment: You could use a larger sheet of paper. You don't tell us what size a page is for you in any case, so we may as well assume A1 or A0 ;).

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example such that we can see how much space is actually available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/big-table-with-rotated-column-labels-using-booktabs

Answer (score 4):

Swapping rows and columns, it can fit a landscape page:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{erewhon}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\setcellgapes[t]{5pt}
\newcommand\niet{\multicolumn{1}{c}{---}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
    \caption{Add caption} \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{l*{3}{>{\checkmark}c}*{4}{>{\checkmark}c}}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Simulation Capabilities} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Other Capabilities}\\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-8}
      Tool Name & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Dynamic\\ Simulation}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Power Flow\\ Calculations}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Renewable Energies\\ modeling (PV \& Wind)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{is Programing\\ required ?}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Ability to export/import\\ to other software}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Verified\\ Library}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Availability\\ in HS}}\\
      \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
      Dymola & & & & & & & \\
      Matlab/Simulink & & & & & & & \\
      ETAP & & & & \niet & & & \niet \\
      PSS/E & & & & \niet & \niet & & \niet \\
      Homer Pro & \niet & & & \niet & \niet & \niet & \niet \\
      Moasik & \niet & & & & & & \niet \\
      ATP Designer & & & & \niet & & \niet & \niet \\
      NEPLAN & & & & & & & \niet \\
      Transmission 2000 & \niet & & \niet & \niet & \niet & \niet & \niet \\
      CYME & & & & & & & \niet \\
      DIgSILENT (PowerFactory) & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{P} & & & & & \\
      SynerGEE Electric & & & & & \niet & & \niet \\
      CAPE & & & \niet & \niet & \niet & & \niet \\
      Eurostag & & & & \niet & \niet & & \niet \\
      IPSA 2 & & & & & \niet & & \niet \\
      MILSOFT Windmil & \niet & & & \niet & \niet & & \niet \\
      SimPowerSystems & & & & & & & \niet \\
      MicroTran & \niet & & \niet & \niet & \niet & \niet & \niet \\
      DSATools & & & & \niet & & & \niet \\
      SIMPOW & & & \niet & \niet & \niet & & \niet \\
      SKM Power*Tools & & & \niet & \niet & \niet & & \niet \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \end{table}%
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of haven `\checkmark` as the standard entry.  Question: For what do you need `\makecell` and why do you add the many `&` between "Dynamic" and "Simulation"?

Comment: Looks like those `&`s actually cause a `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr`… I don't think that could be because I commented out `erewhon` since I don't have it…

Comment: @MickG `erewhon` seems to be a font.  It would be nice if @Bernard could minimalize his example and make it better understandable.

Comment: `Erewhon` is an extension to Adobe Utopia, on which `Fourier` is based. I used it only because it adds true small caps to Utopia ( for caption label). You may safely delete it. For the many `&` between ‘Dynamic’ and ‘Simulation’, they result from a problem with my editor, I'm sorry I didn't notice them on posting. I've updated the code, and you should have no problem now. The `makecell`  command (and package) allows for line breaks in cells of the second row. Also,  `\setcellgapes`, from the same packages, defines some vertical padding for rows, activated by the `\makegapedcells` switch.

Answer (score 4):

How about the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}%[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm}ccccccccccccccccccccc}
%    \toprule
    Tool Name  & \rot{Dymola} & \rot{Matlab/Simulink} & \rot{ETAP} & \rot{PSS/E} & \rot{Homer Pro} & \rot{Moasik} & \rot{ATP Designer} & \rot{NEPLAN} & \rot{Transmission 2000} & \rot{CYME} & \rot{DIgSILENT (PowerFactory)} & \rot{SynerGEE Electric} & \rot{CAPE} & \rot{Eurostag} & \rot{IPSA 2} & \rot{MILSOFT Windmil} & \rot{SimPowerSystems} & \rot{MicroTran} & \rot{DSATools} & \rot{SIMPOW} & \rot{SKM Power*Tools} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Simulation Capabilities}}       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Dynamic Simulation & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & --- & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
    Power Flow Calculations & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
    \hangindent=0.5cm\raggedright
    Renewable Energies modeling (PV \& Wind)
            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & P & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & --- & --- \\
    \textbf{Other capabilities}  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    is Programing required? & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & --- & --- & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & --- & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & --- & --- & --- & --- \\
    \hangindent=0.5cm\raggedright
    Ability to export/import to other software & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & --- & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & --- & --- \\
    Verified Library & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
    Availability in HS & \checkmark & \checkmark & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & \checkmark & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- & --- \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel2}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
```

The ideas are:

1. Use landscape mode (package `lscape` or `pdflscape`)
2. Rotate the long captions of the columns (`\rotatebox` from package `graphicx`)
3. Spread the two longest row captions over two lines: use `p{4.5cm}` instead of `c` for the first column.  To prevent a line break in the title caption "Simulation Capabilities" one can use a `\multicolumn`.  To make the line break clear, make it left aligned and indent the second lines.
4. Decrease the column separation from 6pt (standard value) to 4pt.
5. Replace `-----` by `---` (as suggested by David Carlisle)

[image: The table]

As suggested by Christian Lindig, it is also possible to rotate the column headers by some other angle; see [Rotated column titles in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32683/rotated-column-titles-in-tabular).  This increases the width of the headers, of course, and so one has to take care, that this does not again increase the column separation.  This can be achieved with `\rlab`.  Example:

```
\newcommand*\rot[1]{\rotatebox{60}{\rlap{#1}}}
```

Comment: I like it. Since you are rotating the labels anyway: how about rotating them such that they go slightly diagonal from top-left to bottom-right? This would make them easier to read and the space is available.

Comment: @ChristianLindig Yes, I agree.  I'll mention it in the answer.